# encode a french string eg.éá using utf8 encoding and send as nsdictionary

Tags: ios, encoding

I have a Frech string éá i converted to a readable string bu UTF8encoding but after storing the string as a NSDictionary and sending to Webservice it is again converting to \U00e9ti\U00eb\U00f4 kind of special characters?

```
const char *command1 = [event.eventContactName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:command1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray * rootObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:event.language, [hardware platform], [hardware resolutionString], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion], uuid, LINKMOBILE_VERSION, [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] stringValue], event.net, event.geo, event.userName, event.password, event.nbcall, event.longitude, event.latitude, event.shpId, event.eventFam, event.eventCode, event.eventNat, event.eventCountry, event.eventLoc, event.eventDate, event.eventTime, eventTxt, eventTxt1, doc, nil];

root =     {
        dev = "iPhone5,4";
        document =         (
        );
        evtcod = ARR;
        evtctname = "";
        evtctry = AF;
        evtdate = 20150112;
        evtfam = T;
        evtloc = hhg;
        evtnat = A;
        evttime = "15:11:56";
        evttxt = "\U00c8\U00e0";
        geo = "United Kingdom";
        gpslat = "37.787359";
        gpslon = "-122.408227";
        lang = EN;
        login = mgouache;
        nbcall = 1;
        net = wifi;
        os = "7.1.1";
        pwd = isobar;
        res = 640x1136;
        shp = "12900/62/410829";
        ttp = 1421055743;
        uuid = "15098C22-96A6-48C7-A2E1-E214FEA3CDD1";
        ver = "2.0.0";
    };
```

Comment: Post relevant code. You need to see if the problem is the data sent to the web service or if the problem is with how the web service processes the data.

Comment: Why are you converting a string to `char*` and then back to string? There's no reason to generate cstrings in the middle here. As @rmaddy indicates, you are probably encoding these again at some point later. "\U00e9ti\U00eb\U00f4" is not éá. It's étiáô. And in your `root` data structure (what is this?), you have `evttxt` as ÉÁ, which isn't the same as any of the strings you've described.

Comment: Sorry man , i have send éá kind of french character in a jsondictionary to a wsrequest in log iam getting \U00c8\U00e0 like this is the character reaches in correct format or there is problem in console encoding??? please help me out?

Comment: Do you have reason to think it's not an issue in the logger? Perhaps it's \u-encoding for you. Why do you think the issue is in the ObjC? But if what you're saying is true, it's not just formatting; you're corrupting the data. You say you're sending U+00E9 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE) but it's logging U+00C8 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE). I'd suspect you're running it through something that modifies your data along the way. Check it at each step and see where it goes wrong.